How to write code in Visual Studio Code and open as Visual Studio project?
My C++ class has us making projects with Visual Studio 22, so I use a secondary laptop. I have a 2022 M2 Mac without Visual Studio 22, and have discovered Visual Studio Code as a lightweight alternative for Mac.
I wrote a project in Visual Studio Code and would like to submit it as a Visual Studio project. Is this possible?
I know that Visual Studio Code isn't an IDE and that's a big difference, but I'm wondering if it's possible to repackage my files into Visual Studio?
I tried ChatGPT to get formatted .sln and .vcxproj template files, but that didn't open properly in Visual Studio. I'm wondering if this attempt has any leads.

Even if both tools share Microsoft Visual Studio in their names, they are quite different tools. I have already used different IDE for various languages, but when I want to port a project from one to a distinct one, I generally only port the source files, and rewrite the project part from scratch.

I don't know if the tools are available for ARM macs to create cross-platform solutions via cmake. But I have also never tried. I was going to suggest a VM, but I believe MS is still being stubborn in that regard (ARM images). It's incredibly short-sighted for the class to lock people into one platform. Very little, if any C++ taught at the university level benefits from lock-in.

You shouldn't need the .sln file, a .vcxproj file can be opened directly in Visual Studio (probably can be built directly with MSBuild but I haven't tried).  If you have a working vcxproj file, it's easy to manually modify it to change or add files.

Use Visual Studio Code for Mac. Visual Studio should be used on Windows.

Visual Studio for Mac has been retired as of August 31, 2024 in
accordance with Microsoft’s Modern Lifecycle Policy. Visual Studio for
Mac is no longer supported.

As far as I remember, Visual Studio for Mac did not support C++ in the features introduced by Microsoft.

This is not an answer to their question. It also implicitly says that VS Code is not usable on Windows.
